# zsh: permission denied when Terminal has Full Disk Access

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I regularly use shell files to execute tasks on my Mac quicker.

I just upgraded to MacOS Monterey today, and since then, any shell files I have created, will not execute. Every time I double click on their icon, I get

`zsh: operation not permitted`.

I have given the files proper executable permissions with

`chmod +x my-file.sh` and

`chmod a+x my-file.sh` and

`chmod u+x my-file.sh`,

but none of those work. Shell files I have created in the past still work fine, but it is just new ones that do not.

Terminal has full disk access in System Preferences.

I am stuck, and I don't know what to do, because I use shell files regularly. If anybody has any idea what's going on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Are you sure you didn't create new files from another user? Maybe you accidentally ran `sudo su` before creating new files. What does `ls -la` say? Check the privileges and file owners.
Where do you store your files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you run the scripts from Terminal with `/path/to/my-file.sh` or you also get an `operation not permitted` error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This occurs because of Apple Quarantine:

You can run this:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /PATH/TO/SCRIPTYOUCANTRUN.sh
```

See more here: https://www.alansiu.net/2021/08/19/troubleshooting-zsh-operation-not-permitted/